# How to populate data in browser window?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser

I have a data (list of files) in `$scope.data` from searchFactory , Now i want to display files in browser window. How can i achieve this task ?

ctrl.js

```
$scope.serverFiles = function (){     
   $window.open($scope.data = angular.copy(searchFactory.getDitLogs()));
   console.log("got function working",$scope.data);
};
```

main.html

```
<button
   type="button"
   class="btn btn-info btn-lg"
   ng-click="serverFiles()"
   style="margin-left: 10px">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

declare $scope.data = [] ; then bind it to your view , so any changes it will reflect the changes . that is like this below

```js
angular.module("app", [])
.controller('main', function($scope){
  $scope.data = [];
  
  $scope.serverFiles = function(){
     //dummy record 
    for(i=0;i<10; i++)
      $scope.data.push({sn:(i+1),name:'name of file'+i, file:'file info'+i});
    };
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  
  <div ng-controller="main">
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat = "info in data"><strong>{{info.sn}}</strong> {{info.name}} </li> 
 </ul>

<button ng-click="serverFiles()">Fetch Record</button>
  </div>
  
  </div>
```

anytime you manipulate the $scope.data the view would be updated

Comment: where i will add ng-repeat when i open browser window its not routing froms state its just a window

Comment: oh are you trying to move from one window to another and pass data as parameter to the next page or ?

Comment: i want to send data to browser window and wanted to have some browser feature like sort and date with file names

Comment: oh ok, let me show you like a demo of what you want to achieve

Comment: added the demo, you filter through the ng-repeat using filter

Comment: Above answer does not open browser window and display data into it, My goal is to open browser window and display data in there

Comment: oh ok, if is to route to another page, then use state and state params and not use windows.open use $state.go(ui-sref) instead